# is it acceptable to Require Node modules based on env var's or logic?

Tags: node.js

It might seem like an odd question but I am building a module that abstracts out certain logic for different data storage options. The Idea is that anyone using the module could use it with MongoDb or Redis or SQL or ( *insert whatever option you want here* )

I have a basic interface I am following in each of my implementations by exporting the same function names and signature just with different implementations for each of the various data storage options.

Right now I have a something like `helper = require(process.env.data_storage_helper)`

Then the helper can be used the same way.

Is this bad practise and if so why? Is there a better or suggested way to accomplish this kind of abstraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't technically bad practice, but I would actually add a level of indirection. Instead, have those options stored in configuration files that get picked based on `NODE_ENV` or another environment variable. Then use the same key in the configuration object no matter what. A good example of a framework employing this is [kraken.js](https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-js), which auto-loads a configuration file based on `NODE_ENV`.

You can then grab a handle on the configuration object after Kraken has started up (or whatever you end up using - it uses [confit](https://github.com/krakenjs/confit) under the hood - you can always just use this library directly), and you can grab the `"data_storage_helper"` key to see what your store is backed by within a storage module that does the decision making.

The big pro of this approach is that, now if you'd like to change the data storage or any other behavior of another module, you can just update a JSON file. :-)